# Probability of not drawing all members of subset before drawing the very last number of set.

Tags: probability

I have a set $N$ consisting of $n$ numbers, and a subset of $N$ called $M$, consisting of $m$ numbers.

If one where to draw the numbers from $N$ one by one, what is the probability that all members of $M$ are not drawn before the last member of $N$ is drawn?

I believe the solution to be equivalent to the probability that the last number is a member of $M$, which I'd calculate to be $\frac mn$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The wording seems a bit vague, but I'd interpret it the same way you did, and I agree with your answer.

Comment: Assuming drawing without replacement, and you mean "before the last member of $N - M$ is drawn"...  then Yes.